# The number of Balanced Boolean functions

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra, cryptography

Suppose we have n-variable Boolean function (BF) and we know that the weight of a Balanced BF is $2^{n-1}$. The total number of BFs are $2^{2^n}$, Affine BFs are $2^{n+1}$ and Linear BFs are $2^n$. In general the number of Balanced BF will be greater than the combined number of Affine and Linear BF.

A Balanced BF outputs equal number of $1$s and $0$s.

Affine BF is defined as $f(x)= wx+c$, where $w,x \in F_{2}^n$ and $c \in F_{2}$. The additions whether in dot product or of $c$ are all mod 2 i.e. xor.

An Affine BF is called Linear if $c=0$

From the definitions of Linear and Affine we can deduce their number but I don't have any idea how to find the number of Balanced BF?

Comment: Request: Include the definitions of "Balanced BF", of "Affine BF", and of "Linear BF" so someone reading this can try to help without trying to find definitions somewhere else (which may not even be the same as those you are using). Also when you say "I don't know how to find it", are you just looking for a proof of the inequality?

Comment: Is https://oeis.org/A000721 what you are looking for?

Comment: So if, given the definitions now in the question, each Linear BF is a special case of an Affine BF (with $c=0$), then by "combined number of Affine and Linear BF" it would seem most logical to mean simply the number of Affine BF. Is that correct? [that would mean showing #(Balanced) > #(Affine) is what you want, rather than the stronger inequality #(Balanced) > #(Affine)  #(Linear). To me the last one seems unusual, since on the right one is adding the number of things in a set to the number of things in a subset.

Comment: Yes, you are right that by the "combined number of Affine and Linear BF" I mean the total number of Affine BFs. From the observation we know that #(Balanced BF) > #(Affine BF) ,therefore, I am looking for the exact number of n-variable Balanced BF.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What does the oeis linked sequence count? For n=2 there are 4 truth table rows, and one chooses two of them to be true for binomial(4,2)=6 which agrees with the oeis sequence. But for the next term one would expect binomial(8,4)=70 yet the oeis gives 74 for that term. [Sorry to ask but I thought you might know how they're counting it, and I couldn't find anything other than "same number of 0's as 1's" by a google search.]

Comment: @coffeemath, it's counting equivalence classes of what you're counting, under some symmetry. The 6 is for $n=3$, not $n=2$, and the 74 is for $n=4$. You might want to follow the links and references at the oeis page. Of course, it's possible that what OP wants is just the $2^n$-choose-$2^{n-1}$ that you get with your assumptions, but we'll have to wait to hear from OP about that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; yes, I have also the same intuition that it should be choosing $2^{n-1}$ items from $2^n$ but my problem is how to argue about this. Because we have in total $2^n$ slots and we want $2^{n-1}$ of them to be $0$'s and the other half $1$'s.

Comment: Well, yes, I think that's all there is to it --- $2^n$ slots, and the question is how many ways can you choose $2^{n-1}$ of them to be 1s, and that's just the binomial coefficient @coffeemath and I have mentioned.

Comment: Could this be helpful? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10003420?via%3Dihub